# How to check if environment variable is set from C program

Tags: c, unix, environment-variables

I'm currently working on a program, and I would like to print special output if an environment variable is set.

For example, suppose I want environment variable `"DEBUG"`.

In my bash command prompt, I set `DEBUG` by typing the command:
`DEBUG=`

Then in my C program, I can verify this environment variable is set by printing out all the content of `char **environ`. `DEBUG` does show up in this environment printout.

However, I don't know how to retrieve this environment variable for conditional checking. I've tried using the function getenv like so:

```
getenv("DEBUG")
```

If I were to try to print out this output like below I get a seg fault:

```
printf("get env: %s\n", getenv("DEBUG"));
```

I even tried this on a known environment variable like `"HOME"`:

```
printf("get env: %s\n", getenv("HOME"));
```

which still produces a seg fault.

Does any one have any experience checking if an environment variable is set from a C program? I'm having issues even pulling a single environment variable which is preventing me from doing so.

Comment: What operating system are you working with?

Comment: I'm on OSX, but I'm also testing on a unix/linix server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getenv` returns `NULL` when the environment variable for which it is asked is not set. Your check could thus simply be

```
if(getenv("DEBUG")) {
  // DEBUG is set
} else {
  // DEBUG is not set
}
```

Note that there is a difference between shell and environment variables; if you want a variable to show up in the environment of a shell's subprocess, you have to `export` it in the shell:

```
export DEBUG=some_value
```

or

```
DEBUG=some_value
export DEBUG
```

It is not enough to just say `DEBUG=some_value`.

Comment: How do you explain the segmentation fault with the `getenv("HOME");`?

Comment: He's printing NULL as a string.

Comment: `getenv("HOME")` will unlikely return `NULL`, and also I suspect the OP is on linux using `glibc`, where `printf("%s\n", NULL);` will in fact output `(null)`.

Comment: I'm on x86-64 Linux, and I get a segfault when I try to `printf("%s\n", NULL);` (with glibc 2.19). You have a point about `$HOME`, though.

Comment: I just did the same `printf("%s\n", NULL);` and of course a warning was issued, but it didn't crash, it just outputs `(null)`, what could be the difference?

Comment: @iharob That can only be a library issue, I should think. Maybe you have a newer/older glibc than I where this is handled differently.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my problem was that I'm trying to write my own library version of some of the stdlib functions and thus didn't include stdlib.h

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that `getenv` (and `printf`) are correctly declared.

For `getenv`, you need:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

If you don't declare it, segfaults are likely when you call it. If you were to get that far, trying to use the value it returns would probably also segfault.

Undeclared functions are handled as though they were declared to accept either integer or double arguments (depending on what is provided) and as though they return integers. If `int` is the same size as a pointer, that might work, but in the common case where pointers are 64 bits but ints are only 32, passing a pointer as though it were an integer will result in half of its bits being dropped on the floor, making it pretty much unusable as a pointer.

*Always*  specify `-Wall` when you compile your code, and make sure you pay attention to the warnings. They are important.

Comment: @iharob: Given 64-bit pointers and 32-bit integers, a segfault is almost inevitable if you call an undeclared function which takes a pointer as an argument, since the default `int` conversion will drop the high bits from the pointer.

Comment: I now... And since you didn't mention the default returning `int` issue, I added a new answer to address that.

Comment: @iharob: it probably never gets to the return. But I put an explanation in the answer, fwiw. (Although the correct explanation is, of course, "UB yadda yadda yadda.") If I had more energy I'd look for the dupe.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I am trying to write my own stdlib version of functions and thus did not include that library, but I'll try adding it in

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are not including `stdlib.h` and the compiler is assuming `getenv()` returns `int`.

You have two options, you can declare `getenv()` like

```
char *getenv(const char *);
```

or include `stdlib.h`, and the same applies for `printf()` but in that case the header is `stdio.h`.

You should enable compiler warning, on linux `gcc` and `clang` both support `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`, the most important one, `-Werror` will prevent compilation in this case.

Answer (score 1):

code snippet :

```
   if(NULL == getenv("TIME_ELAPSED"))
    {
        putenv("TIME_ELAPSED=1");
    }
```

we have to take care of error handling for putenv also .Sometimes it returns 
ENOMEM Insufficient space to allocate new environment.